# Hide one div and show another one with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I’d like two hide one div and show another one with animation from right to left and the progress bar has to stay in its position. The one already visible has to hide from right to left and the one that is hidden has to become visible with animation from right to left. I saw that with position: absolute on the two div can work, but then the progress bar would move up the page, above the divs. How could you do it?
The div that is already visible is "RegisterChoice" and I want to hide it and show "RegisterChoiceEmail".
I use React and bootstrap for the progress bar.
Thanks in advance!

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import "jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-slide";
import {ProgressBar, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Register, RegisterChoice, RegisterChoiceEmail, RegisterChoiceH1, RegisterChoiceWrapper, RegisterChoiceWrapperEmail, RegisterChoiceCard, RegisterChoiceIcon, RegisterChoiceH2} from './SceltaRegistrazioneElements'
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';
import {FaFacebookF} from 'react-icons/fa';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button';

const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.profileObj);
}

const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.profileObj);
}

const Registrazione = () => {
    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(20);
    let active = 'registerChoice';
    function RegisterChoiceClicked() {
        return (
            $("#"+active ).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500),
            $("#registerChoiceEmail").delay(600).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500).css("display", "flex"),
            setPercentage((oldPercentage) => {
                return oldPercentage + 20;
            })
        )
    }

    return (
        <Register>
            <RegisterChoice id="registerChoice">
                <RegisterChoiceH1>Sei una struttura, vuoi diventare un pet sitter o un cliente?</RegisterChoiceH1>
                <RegisterChoiceWrapper>
                    <RegisterChoiceCard onClick={RegisterChoiceClicked}>
                        <RegisterChoiceIcon src={require('../../../images/structure.jpg').default}/>
                        <RegisterChoiceH2>Struttura</RegisterChoiceH2>
                    </RegisterChoiceCard>
                    <RegisterChoiceCard onClick={RegisterChoiceClicked}>
                        <RegisterChoiceIcon src={require('../../../images/petSitter.jpg').default}/>
                        <RegisterChoiceH2>Pet sitter</RegisterChoiceH2>
                    </RegisterChoiceCard>
                    <RegisterChoiceCard onClick={RegisterChoiceClicked}>
                        <RegisterChoiceIcon src={require('../../../images/client.jpg').default}/>
                        <RegisterChoiceH2>Cliente</RegisterChoiceH2>
                    </RegisterChoiceCard>
                </RegisterChoiceWrapper>
            </RegisterChoice>
            <RegisterChoiceEmail id="registerChoiceEmail">
                <RegisterChoiceH1>Come vuoi registrarti?</RegisterChoiceH1>
                <RegisterChoiceWrapperEmail>
                    <Button variant="primary w-50" style={{marginBottom: "20px", height: "50px", minWidth: "240px", width: "50%"}} onClick={RegisterChoiceClicked}>Accedi con l'email</Button>
                    <FacebookLogin
                        appId=""
                        autoLoad={false}
                        fields="name,email,picture"
                        callback={responseFacebook}
                        textButton="Registrati con Facebook"
                        icon={<FaFacebookF  style={{marginRight: "10px", marginBottom: "3px"}}></FaFacebookF>}
                        cssClass="btnFacebook"
                        language="it_IT"
                    />
                    <GoogleLogin
                        clientId=""
                        buttonText="Accedi con Google"
                        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                        onFailure={responseGoogle}
                        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                        isSignedIn={true}
                        language="it_IT"
                        render={renderProps => (
                            <GoogleButton 
                                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                                label='Registrati con Google'
                                style={{fontWeight: "700", fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif", WebkitFontSmoothing: "antialiased", justifyContent: "center", minWidth: "240px", width: "50%"}}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </RegisterChoiceWrapperEmail>
            </RegisterChoiceEmail>
            <ProgressBar id="progressBar" striped animated variant="success" now={percentage} style={{width: "70%", margin: "90px auto"}} />
        </Register>
    )
}

export default Registrazione
```

**In another file, 'RegistrazioneElements.js':**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Register = styled.div`
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #010606;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
`

export const RegisterChoice = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    clear: both;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
        padding: 20px;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceEmail = styled.div`
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
        padding: 20px;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceWrapper = styled.div`
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    padding: 40px 50px;
    width: 70%;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1250px){
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        padding: 0px 0px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 980px){
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceWrapperEmail = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 50px;
    width: 70%;
    justify-content: center;
    > {
        text-align: center;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceCard = styled.div`
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 340px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 0.2 ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.02);
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceIcon = styled.img`
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
`

export const RegisterChoiceH1 = styled.h1`
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 150px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
`

export const RegisterChoiceH2 = styled.h2`
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
`
```

Comment: Never use jQuery alongside any vDom library (in this case react). You are screwing your self over big time.

Comment: Ok, ty. I hope i will find a solution because I've been trying for some time

Comment: begin with creating the desired effect in a small standalone test project. It's a lot easier to work with a small project when learning something new. I would recommend starting with pure vanilla js. Then once you got the effect working, start moving over to react.